# How to detect when all fingers have left the screen

Tags: ios, ios8, touch-event

I want to exactly detect the time when all finger have left the finger.

But when I tested with
`-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

I found use `touches.count == event.allTouches.count` not always work.

Answer (score 1):

Touches ended might be called for some or all of the touches performed by the user. If you are tracking multiple simultaneous touches you will need to keep a count of all of them on `touchesBegan` and then subtract from that count on `touchesEnded` until you get Zero.

`touches.count == touches.count` Will always be equal, since you are comparing one thing with itself.

- create a `NSInteger` instance variable
- increment it by `touches.count` in `touchesBegan`
- decrease it by `touches.count` in `touchesEnded`
- check if your count is zero.

Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry, I was compared touches.count == event.allTouches.count

Answer (score 0):

> touches.count == event.allTouches.count not always work

Every individual touch "belongs" to a view (the view to which its initially hit-tested). The only touches in the `touches` NSSet are those directed towards *this* view. The event, however, may contain touches belonging to other views. Thus you are not going to be able to detect when the whole multitouch event is over in this way. In fact, if the user stops touching this view but has other fingers down, this view won't get *any* event for that.

Comment: Might want to consult the docs; my book also explains about touches and touch events: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_touch_events_and_views